# Using FreeQ with implicit functions

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, expression-test

In Mathematica 7, I want to determine whether a list of free of numbers greater than 1 or not.  It seems like using `FreeQ` would be a concise way to do this:

```
FreeQ[{2, 1}, # > 1 &] (* The output is: True *)

FreeQ[{1, 1}, # > 1 &] (* The output is: True *)
```

Why does `FreeQ[{2, 1}, # > 1 &]` give `True`?  `{2, 1}` is not free of numbers greater than 1, so I must be using `FreeQ` incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FreeQ[]` expects an object or a *pattern* as its second argument, as opposed to a Boolean function. What you should be doing is `FreeQ[{2, 1}, _?(# > 1 &)]`. Yes, the parentheses are needed.

A similar statement applies to the other [pattern-matching functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PatternMatchingFunctions.html) of *Mathematica*, e.g. `Cases[]`, `Position[]`, and `MatchQ[]`.

Comment: Ah, I made a silly mistake!  Thank you for being patient and gentle with me.

Answer (score 2):

Supporting J.M.'s answer you could also use `Condition` rather than `PatternTest`:

```
FreeQ[{2, 1}, x_ /; x > 1]
```

This is usually slightly faster.  Faster still in many cases is `Max`, assuming numeric data:

```
Max[{2, 1}] <= 1
```